# Html.DropDownListFor loads with wrong value first time, but correct every time afterward?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on an MVC5 application (Oracle DB), and noticed some odd behaviour with a binded dropdownlist on my view. When I select a record for Edit, my `GET-Edit` controller action loads a list of names from my `TBL_OWNERS`, sorted by `[OWNER_NAME]` into my ViewData object:

```
ViewData["Owner_List"] = new SelectList(db.TBL_OWNERS.OrderBy(x => x.OWNER_NAME), "ID", "OWNER_NAME");
```

Then on my View, I use this ViewData list to fill a SelectList that populates the DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OWNER, (SelectList)ViewData["Owner_List"], "NONE", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown", @id = "selectOwner" })
```

Now then, when I select a record to edit which does not have a value for `[OWNER]`, I get the expected default value of "NONE" as the selected option in the Dropdown. However, if I have a value for `[OWNER]` (ex.) "SMITH, JOHN", the View loads still displaying "NONE" in the dropdown.

What is so odd, is that if I then save the record (specifying ANY name from the dropdown), the next time I go into my Edit View for that record the dropdown is already pre-selected to the proper value already stored in the Oracle DB.

Can anyone with more experience weigh in on what is going on here and how to fix it?

---

For some extra information (if it helps) my main DAL class has the `[OWNER]` field defined as:

```
[StringLength(4000)]
public string OWNER { get; set; }
```

And then I also have a MetaData class for this main class defined:

```
namespace Project.DAL
{

    // This MetaData partial class is used to extend properties of the [ENT_COLLECTIONS] DAL class
    // allowing for new properties to be set explicitly filled with related FK values.
    [MetadataType(typeof(ENT_COLLECTIONSMD))]
    public partial class ENT_COLLECTIONS
    {

        // .... Other MetaData Fields ...

        [Display(Name = "Owner")]
        public string Owner_Name
        {
            get
            {
                // TBL_OWNERS is not linked to ENT_COLLECTIONS like the other child tables (Locations, Types, etc.)
                // Need to retrieve the [OWNER_NAME] from [ENT_OWNERS] to specify for [ENT_COLLECTIONS].[OWNER] instead of
                // (ex.) "47" for the value.

                // Band-Aid for Exporting where OWNER (ex.) "Smith, John" cannot be converted to a Decimal. If values is < 4 (ID), then proceed.
                if (this.OWNER != null && this.OWNER.Length < 4)
                {
                    // Convert the values of [ENT_COLLECTIONS].[OWNER] to decimal ("47" => 47)
                    var ownerID = Convert.ToDecimal(this.OWNER);
                    // Match this ID to [TBL_OWNERS].[ID] to get the singular referenced [TBL_OWNERS] entity.
                    var ownerEntity = db.TBL_OWNERS.FirstOrDefault(model => model.ID == ownerID);
                    // If a match was found, change [OWNER] from (ex.) "47" to "SMTIH, JOHN"
                    if (ownerEntity != null)
                    {
                        this.OWNER = ownerEntity.OWNER_NAME;
                    }
                }

                return this.OWNER;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ENT_COLLECTIONSMD
    {
        // ... Other Fields ...

        [StringLength(4000)]
        public string OWNER;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ViewData["Owner_List"] = new SelectList(db.TBL_OWNERS.OrderBy(x => x.OWNER_NAME), "ID", "OWNER_NAME");
> ```

you should use a different constructor, as you're not specifying the selected item in the list.
The MVC helper DropdownListFor doesn't automatically selects the value, and expects you to tell the SelectList what item is selected.

The correct way to initialize that SelectList is:

```
ViewData["Owner_List"] = new SelectList(db.TBL_OWNERS.OrderBy(x => x.OWNER_NAME), "ID", "OWNER_NAME", [OWNER_ID]);
```

Referring to the strange behavior you're seeing about the item being already selected when you go back to the view, it's probably your web browser trying to autocomplete the select. You should do a test specifying `autocomplete="off"` as html property.

You can find a similar question here: [How to make a select list item selected in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779741/how-to-make-a-select-list-item-selected-in-asp-net-mvc)

PS: As a side note, try not to use ViewData if you're not forced to do it. Using a model and a strongly typed view is almost always better.

Comment: When I try the following, the section after `"ID", "OWNER_NAME"` flags with `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' becuase it is not a delegate type`? `ENT_COLLECTIONS ent_Collections = await db.ENT_COLLECTIONS.FindAsync(id); ViewData["Owner_List"] = new SelectList(db.TBL_OWNERS.OrderBy(x => x.OWNER_NAME), "ID", "OWNER_NAME", x => x.OWNER_NAME == ent_Collections.OWNER);` Visual Studio flags your suggested addition as error.

Comment: Yes you're right, I corrected the code. Don't know why but I really thought I saw a Func signature somewhere

Comment: I had hoped this might do the trick, but I'm still getting the exact same behavior as before -- "NONE" showing up for a valid "OWNER" value being present the first time, then correct each time thereafter once an initial Save is performed. `ViewData["Owner_List"] = new SelectList(db.INV_OWNERS.OrderBy(x => x.OWNER_NAME), "ID", "OWNER_NAME", ent_Collections.OWNER);`

Comment: I should have been more clear, you have to use the I'd value to match the "ID" parameter you specified at the second place of the constructor. Also, try to add autocomplete="off" to your HTML properties to see if the odd behavior stops. I'm correcting the code for clarity again

Comment: It's still doing the same thing. I added `<input autocomplete="off">` to my View, and I'm now passing the [OwnerID] instead of the [Owner_Name] for that new parameter you showed: `decimal ownerID = db.INV_OWNERS.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OWNER_NAME == ent_Collections.OWNER).ID;` -- `ViewData["Owner_List"] = new SelectList(db.INV_OWNERS.OrderBy(x => x.OWNER_NAME), "ID", "OWNER_NAME", ownerID);` Still the same behavior as before.

Comment: I thought I had it after reviewing the other post you linked to in your answer, but still no luck with the following: `int ownerID = 0; if (ent_Collections.OWNER != null) {  ownerID = Convert.ToInt32(db.INV_OWNERS.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OWNER_NAME == ent_Collections.OWNER).ID);  }` -- `ViewData["Owner_List"] = new SelectList(db.INV_OWNERS.OrderBy(x => x.OWNER_NAME), "ID", "OWNER_NAME", id = ownerID);` Exact same behavior as before.